# GoogleApiClient is deprecated, New alternative

Tags: android, google-api

```
public class DriverMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/FIDeomTlYHI?list=PLxabZQCAe5fgXx8cn2iKOtt0VFJrf5bOd), but all GoogleApiClients are crossed out and I don't understand why!

Answer (score 12):

Use GoogleApi instead of GoogleApiClient: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApi.html

This guide walks you through how to transition from GoogleApiClient to GoogleApi:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/moving-past-googleapiclient_21.html